# supervisord and celery warm shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, redis, celery, supervisord

Whenever I run "sudo shutdown -h now" on an ubuntu instance that runs Supervisor and Celery, it seems Celery just shuts down in the middle of processing tasks, when looking at the tail -f I don't see the "warm shutdown" message you would usually see when you type ctrl-C while Celery runs in the foreground.

This is for me a big issue because servers may be terminated any time, and so waiting for Celery to finish processing its tasks is critical. It may take a few seconds, 10 minute or 10 hours, but a shutdown signal should always let Celery finish its work. 
I have added stopasgroup and killasgroup in my celeryd configuration file, and it does seem like stopping Celery from supervisor stops all of the subprocesses, but somehow it seems to ignore the shutdown signal sent by "sudo shutdown -h now".

Does anyone have an idea why Celery doesn't show the usual "Warm Shutdown" it would get normally?

Here is an example of a worker conf:

```
[program:celery-worker]
command=/path/to/script-running-celery.sh
directory=/path/to/celery/project/tasks
user=myuser
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 60
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
priority=50
```

And here is the actual shell script that is being run:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="$PATH:/mylocal-envs/localenv";
cd /path/to/celery/project/tasks;
exec /mylocal-envs/localenv/bin/celery worker -c8 -n my_worker_%h_$(uuid) --without-gossip -A tasks --queues=myqueue --loglevel=INFO -Ofair
```

Can you see a reason why a shutdown command would not let Celery run in warm shutdown and wrap up its current tasks?

Edit: Just a note, when running my script directly without using Supervisor and shut down from another ssh window, I still get the same behavior: The worker is processing tasks, then the shutdown signal is received and the ssh session is closed. Here is what happens from the worker foreground when running the script:

```
[2014-05-17 19:29:02,955: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.a_task[5143a89d-e077-4145-ba94-0932d0f81d9e] succeeded in 15.523131618s: u''
[2014-05-17 19:29:03,621: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.a_task[b61a30ba-2fbb-475a-9cb2-ec88d20a8885]

Broadcast message from jdoe@10.0.0.12
    (/dev/pts/1) at 19:29 ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
[2014-05-17 19:29:06,846: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.a_task[9146f9f4-f06c-4563-b8d1-43c8d9367d9b]
[2014-05-17 19:29:08,089: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.a_task[b4c7dacc-3f6d-42e5-ab67-f33748f0af14] succeeded in 16.49714411s: u''
Connection to xx.xx.xxx.xx closed by remote host.
Connection to xx.xx.xxx.xx closed.
```

You can still see that a task succeeds, another one is received. Looking at flower, I see a bunch of tasks that were started and are now stuck in "Started" or "Received".

Edit: After trying to run celery directly in the command= option instead of running a shell script, I notice the same behavior. If I run my script (with celery in debug mode) over ssh in the foreground, I'll get the following when hitting ctrl-C:

```
worker: Hitting Ctrl+C again will terminate all running tasks!
289
290worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
291[2014-05-18 13:12:49,557: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Hub...
292[2014-05-18 13:12:49,557: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Pool...
293[2014-05-18 13:12:49,557: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Closing Consumer...
294[2014-05-18 13:12:49,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Consumer...
295[2014-05-18 13:12:49,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Connection...
296[2014-05-18 13:12:49,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Events...
297[2014-05-18 13:12:49,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Mingle...
298[2014-05-18 13:12:49,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Tasks...
299[2014-05-18 13:12:49,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Control...
300[2014-05-18 13:12:49,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing Heart...
301[2014-05-18 13:12:49,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Closing event loop...
302[2014-05-18 13:12:49,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping event loop...
303[2014-05-18 13:12:49,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Heart...
304[2014-05-18 13:12:49,564: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Control...
305[2014-05-18 13:12:49,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Tasks...
306[2014-05-18 13:12:49,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] Cancelling task consumer...
307[2014-05-18 13:12:49,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Mingle...
308[2014-05-18 13:12:49,570: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Events...
309[2014-05-18 13:12:49,571: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Stopping Connection...
310[2014-05-18 13:12:49,571: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Pool...
311[2014-05-18 13:12:50,608: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Stopping Hub...
312[2014-05-18 13:12:50,612: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Heart...
313[2014-05-18 13:12:50,612: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Control...
314[2014-05-18 13:12:50,613: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Tasks...
315[2014-05-18 13:12:50,614: DEBUG/MainProcess] Cancelling task consumer...
316[2014-05-18 13:12:50,614: DEBUG/MainProcess] Closing consumer channel...
317[2014-05-18 13:12:50,615: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Events...
318[2014-05-18 13:12:50,616: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Shutdown Connection...
319[2014-05-18 13:12:50,617: DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
```

This looks like the normal shutdown process which I'd like to see happen with supervisor.
On the other hand, stopping using supervisor gives me the following:

```
[2014-05-18 13:14:28,369: DEBUG/MainProcess] pidbox received method ping() [reply_to:{u'routing_key': u'1bcaf3a6-0c77-33b9-9d46-56e8634e5b1d', u'exchange': u'reply.celery.pidbox'} ticket:161fcbdb-dac0-48c9-ac13-ab7a75bfdc85]
```

There is none of the shutdown trace like the one you see when hitting ctrl-c. It simply stops.

Comment: It looks like I should be somehow passing the TERM signal from my shell script into the celery process running in the foreground with exec. Somehow Supervisor manages the shell script but not the celery workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the version of Supervisor that ships with Ubuntu (3.0a.) After switching to the current stable version of Supervisor (manually installing in /usr/local/bin), I can see the logs that the sigterm is indeed being received.